# How to get numbers with the loop from another function

Tags: javascript

i want to get numbers between 1 to 25. With the first function i get all numbers between 1 to 25 after that i want to get all these numbers in the second function and place each of them in separated td. Now it is undefined, i can not get the numbers from the first function.

```js
function range(arr1, arr2){
 var arr = [];
 for( var i = arr1; i <= arr2; i++ ){
  arr.push(arr2[i]);
 }
 return arr;
}

function createTable(arr){
 // var arr = [];
 var table = document.createElement("table");
 for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = arr[i];
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  table.appendChild(td);
 }
 return;

}
createTable(range(1, 25));
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid green;

}
```

Comment: *"With the first function i get all numbers between 1 to 25"* – Did you try *confirming* that assumption…?

Comment: Lots of issues. the range function does not work since `arr2[i]` basically comes down to: give me the i'th character in the string arr2. And arr2 is the number 25, so it only has 2 characters. And in createTable, add all the options to the table, then add the table to the document. No need to add the table to the document every time you add a cell. Also, you add table cells, without adding table rows. This might work, but onl;y because the browser corrects the mistakes automatically.

Comment: @Shilly `arr2[i]` means *get __property__ `i` of object `arr2`*, and Numbers don't have properties called `0` or `1` or such by default…

Comment: @deceze Guess I wrongly assumed it would get casted to a string when trying this, then my comment would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `arr.push(arr2[i]);` to `arr.push(i);` in your `range` function

`arr2` is a number so `arr2[i]` is always undefined

```js
function range(arr1, arr2){
 var arr = [];
 for( var i = arr1; i <= arr2; i++ ){
  arr.push(i);
 }
 return arr;
}

function createTable(arr){
 // var arr = [];
 var table = document.createElement("table");
 for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = arr[i];
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  table.appendChild(td);
 }
 return;

}
createTable(range(1, 25));
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid green;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In range function make below change:
Push(i) instead of push(arr2[i])

```
function range(arr1, arr2){
var arr = [];
for( var i = arr1; i <= arr2; i++ ){
    arr.push(i);
}
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `range()` function uses `arr2` as an array (`arr.push(arr2[i])`) as well as number.

You could rewrite it like this:

```js
function range(lowerBound, upperBound) {
    return [...Array(upperBound - lowerBound + 1).keys()].map((x) => (x + lowerBound));
}
```